# Exist any way of sort alphanumeric in ruby using a unpack command?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to sort alphanumeric using `unpack` command in Ruby but it doesn't work my and I don't know how to solve this.

This is my list:

```
accidentally
accommodation
accompany
according to
account
account for
accurate
accurately
accuse
achieve
achievement
acid
acknowledge
a couple
acquire
across
act
action
active
actively
activity
actor
actress
actual
actually
ad
adapt
add
addition
additional
add on
address
add up
add up to
adequate
adequately
adjust
admiration
admire
admit
adopt
adult
advance
advanced
advantage
adventure
advert
advertise
advertisement
advertising
advice
advise
affair
affect
affection
afford
afraid
after
afternoon
afterwards
again
against
age
aged
agency
agent
aggressive
ago
agree
agreement
ahead
aid
aim
air
aircraft
airport
alarm
alarmed
a
abandon
abandoned
ability
able
about
above
abroad
absence
absent
absolute
absolutely
absorb
abuse
abuse
academic
accent
accept
acceptable
access
accident
accidental
```

I use this command:

```
    ruby -e 'array = File.read("lista").lines ;sum= Hash.new(0); m5g= array.sort_by { |l| +l.split(";")[0].unpack("B*")[0].to_i }.join("");print m5g' >fsssfff3
```

And I obtain this:

```
a
ad
act
add
age
ago
aid
aim
air
able
acid
aged
about
above
abuse
abuse
actor
adapt
admit
adopt
adult
after
again
agent
agree
ahead
alarm
abroad
absent
absorb
accent
accept
access
accuse
across
action
active
actual
add on
add up
adjust
admire
advert
advice
advise
affair
affect
afford
afraid
agency
abandon
ability
absence
account
achieve
acquire
actress
address
advance
against
airport
alarmed
a couple
absolute
academic
accident
accurate
actively
activity
actually
addition
adequate
advanced
aircraft
abandoned
accompany
add up to
advantage
adventure
advertise
affection
afternoon
agreement
absolutely
acceptable
accidental
accurately
additional
adequately
admiration
afterwards
aggressive
account for
achievement
acknowledge
advertising
accidentally
according to
accommodation
advertisement
```

Is it possible to use another `unpack` decodification `.unpack('B*')` for doing this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What's the expected output? Maybe try reducing your example to the smallest set of input that demonstrates the problem, the actual output and the expected output will make more people likely to help you out.

Comment: As @SimpleLime advises, state your question and reduce the size of your example (to less than 10 items, say). Don't force readers to use `uppack` or any other method, as it may not work or there may be better approaches. State your question in words. When giving an example, show all inputs as valid Ruby objects, assign a variable to each input object (e..g., `str =  "a\nad\nact\nadnage\nago\n"`) and show the desired output. By assigning variables to example inputs readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.